# Automation of conversion from .Rnw to .Rmd

Tags: r, knitr

Has anyone automated conversion of `R no-web` to `R markdown`?  I tried to use `pandoc` for this but the `.Rnw` file confused it.  Even a partial solution would help.  Otherwise I will have a lot of hand-editing to do.

Comment: I'd say that this is practically impossible. However, to give a more elaborate answer, could you please explain what you actually want to achieve? Why the conversion? Which output format of the RMD file? And, most importantly: What kinds of LateX-voodoo is embedded in the original RNW file?

Comment: I should have been more specific.  I'm taking an `.Rnw` beamer presentation  and converting it to [`xaringan`](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan) so I can edit it further.  The source has the advantage of being highly structured so I may be able to do the first cut using a sed script with many, many regular expression replacement clauses.

Comment: I would try to do it like this:  convert Rnw to .tex using Sweave/knitr.  Convert tex to md using pandoc.  Manually replace the R output with code chunks by hand using a side-by-side comparision tool (I use Beyond Compare, but there are lots of them) that can sync to the text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In the end I wrote a script that applies a series of regular expression substitutions.  It is not a general solution but because I knew how the structure of the LaTeX in the source files well I could do the conversion.

Comment: I came across [this](https://github.com/mdsr-book/mdsr/blob/master/R/Rnw2Rmd.R) today, but haven't tested it yet.